# SQL error after clearing logs: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '12953' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: error, log

```
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
> '12953' for key 'PRIMARY' Trace:
> #0 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(283):
> Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
> #1 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(457):
> Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
> #2 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(230):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
> #3 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(281):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
> #4 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(535):
> Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
> #5 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Mysql4/Visitor.php(125):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('log_visitor_inf...', Array)
> #6 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Mysql4/Visitor.php(79):
> Mage_Log_Model_Mysql4_Visitor->_saveVisitorInfo(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
> #7 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(373):
> Mage_Log_Model_Mysql4_Visitor->_afterSave(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
> #8 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(251):
> Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
> #9 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(159):
> Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
> #10 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1239):
> Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
> #11 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/app/Mage.php(303):
> Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
> #12 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(454):
> Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
> #13 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(45):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
> #14 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(365):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
> #15 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(248):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
> #16 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(158):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
> #17 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/app/Mage.php(459):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
> #18 /data01/virt27417/domeenid/www.kinkeraamat.ee/gizmos/index.php(65):
> Mage::run()
> #19 {main}
```

Comment: what happened leading up to this?

Answer (score 2):

user20889,clea`r truncate all log table` from `database`.it issue `foreign` key and primary key issue.
Please truncate below table:

```
log_customer
log_quote
log_summary
log_summary_type
log_url
log_url_info
log_visitor
log_visitor_info
log_visitor_online
```